# Open save as dialog on newly opened window

Tags: javascript, jquery

How in JS/jQuery do I pop open the "Save As" dialog for a newly opened window.  Basically I am scraping some data off of a web page.  As such I am opening a new window via:

```
dataWindow = window.open('blank','dataWindow');
```

I then write the output to the blank window but I want to automatically pop open the "Save As" dialog to save the content of the window to a file (text/csv).  How would I do this.  I tried:

```
dataWindow.document.execCommand("saveAs",true,".txt");
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Don't care if it works in IE...I only need it to work in Firefox

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how to send the content-disposition header using JS once the output is sent to the window.

Answer (score 2):

execCommand is not an ideal way to do this kind of thing, since it's a pretty browser-specific extension to javascript.

There's a [good suggestion in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833015/does-execcommand-saveas-work-in-firefox) to make a Save As dialog happen by returning a content-disposition header to make the browser think that the content is an attachment.

Edit:  [This other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399486/open-the-save-image-dialog-using-jquery-javascript) also has some suggestions along the same lines.