# Downloading mp3 files using html5 blobs in a chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, blob

I am trying to create a google-chrome-extension that will download an mp3 file. I am trying to use HTML5 blobs and an iframe to trigger a download, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
var finalURL = "server1.example.com/u25561664/audio/120774.mp3";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", finalURL, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) 
        {   
            var bb = new (window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder)();
            bb.append(xhr.responseText);
            var blob = bb.getBlob("application/octet-stream");

            var saveas = document.createElement("iframe");
            saveas.style.display = "none";

            saveas.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob); 

            document.body.appendChild(saveas);

            delete xhr;
            delete blob;
            delete bb;
        }
    }
 xhr.send();
```

When looked in the console, the blob is created correctly, the settings look right:

size: 15312172
type: "application/octet-stream"

However, when I try the link created by the `createObjectURL()`,

> blob:chrome-extension://dkhkkcnjlmfnnmaobedahgcljonancbe/b6c2e829-c811-4239-bd06-8506a67cab04

I get a blank document and a warning saying

> Resource interpreted as Document but
>   transferred with MIME type
>   application/octet-stream.

How can get my code to download the file correctly?

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation. I'm using chrome. For me, xhr.status returns 0. Does that mean XMLHttpRequest don't support cross domain scripting? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: XMLHttpRequests must follow cross-domain policy. If you want to call a page from another domain, you will need to add the domain in the manifest file for the extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code worked for me in Google chrome 14.0.835.163:

```
var finalURL = "http://localhost/Music/123a4.mp3";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream");
//xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhr.open("GET", finalURL, true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function() {
      var bb = new (window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder)();
      var res = xhr.response;
      if (res){
          var byteArray = new Uint8Array(res);
      }
      bb.append(byteArray.buffer);
      var blob = bb.getBlob("application/octet-stream");
      var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      iframe.style.display = "none";
      iframe.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: @Xan any browser with Blobs has XHR2 so doing `onreadystatechange` is redundant at best (you can just `onload`), using `delete` in a GC'd environment is just plain silly and will do nothing in this case (in particular, you can't `delete` what you defined with `var` it's a no-op). I just changed those two things - this answer can be improved a lot further but I didn't want to change its meaning - just the smaller syntax issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i think this is your server's trouble. I've just tried your piece of code to download some sample blob of mp3-file and everything went ok. So maybe:

1. this file doesn't exist on your server
2. you server outputs wrong mime type for mp3 files

Comment: I checked and the file exists on the server, and I am pretty sure that the MIME type is correct. How can I check the mime type that the server is outputting?

Comment: The simplest way is to fetch "Content-type" response header:
xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-type');

Comment: I am getting back "audio/mpeg". Can you not use octet-stream for that? Switching getBlob to use "audio/mpeg" gives the same problem.