# Using Javascript to add custom http header and trigger file download

Tags: javascript, http-headers, download

I would like to start a simple file download through the browser, however an access token must be passed with a custom HTTP header:

```
GET https://my.site.com/some/file
Authorization: access_token
```

How can I inject the *Authorization:* header following the site URL?
I know it's possible to do that using query string, but I want to do it using headers.

I'm familiar with XMLHttpRequest, but as far as I understand it does not trigger download, it only reads content and the file I want to download is few hundred MBs at least.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'access_token');
```

This looks like a simple task, but I'm inexperienced coder so any help would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Why not do it on the serverside, where you'd normally set the headers ?

Comment: Because file I want to download is not on my server. My server only generates token.
Also, I do not want to use any PHP relaying since this would cost me a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this solves your problem:

```
function toBinaryString(data) {
    var ret = [];
    var len = data.length;
    var byte;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        byte=( data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF )>>> 0;
        ret.push( String.fromCharCode(byte) );
    }

    return ret.join('');
}


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

xhr.open( "GET", "https://my.site.com/some/file" );     

xhr.addEventListener( "load", function(){
    var data = toBinaryString(this.responseText);
    data = "data:application/text;base64,"+btoa(data);
    document.location = data;
}, false);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "access_token" );
xhr.overrideMimeType( "application/octet-stream; charset=x-user-defined;" );
xhr.send(null);
```

Modified answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10518190/2767026 to fit your needs.

Comment: Is it possible to put a custom filename for the download?

Comment: @Oleksii I dont know, answered a long time ago and at the time this code fit my needs... :( I'm sorry.

Comment: Actually it is. As so: link.attr({
                    "href": data,
                    "download": name + new Date().valueOf() + ext
                })

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add custom http header when you download a file by clicking on a link.

However, in your use case, you might store the token in a cookie, which will be automatically added to all browser requests.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12372670/1961561 could be a solution for your problem.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/test",
  headers: {"X-Test-Header": "test-value"}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it look like what i want, but i don't use jQuery.
Is the a way to do this in "pure javascript"?

Comment: Nop, it still does not trigger download.

Comment: You can't use ajax to download and save a file to disk for security reasons