# Download a file with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to provide a link to download a file, the link must be hidden and accessible by any users, Here is my code , there are no errors whatsoever, but I can't even get the download dialog box to open:

Template

```
 <a ng-href="#" target="page" type="button" class="btn" 
ng-click="download()">Download</a>
```

Script file

```
$scope.download = function(){
 //here i need to know the code,can anybody explain me
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your can't "hide/not public" a link in a web based technology (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) application. Downloads are handled by the client, so the Download/Link-URL must be public. You can try to "hide" protective params like e.g. IDs in the download URL by using a backend executed programming language like "PHP or node.js, etc.". In that way you can create `hash` URLs like `http://www.myside.com/download/359FTBW!S3T387IHS` to hide parameters like the `recordId` in your URL.

By knowing this, your solution is pretty easy. Just use the [HTML attribute download](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) like  `<a href="http://mydownloadurl" download>link text</a>` to force the browser to download the `href` source. No `ng-click` is needed here. Unfortunately the `download` attribute is not supported by Safari browser. This doesn't realy matter while the browser is handling the download itself. Depending on the users system OS configuration the file will be downloaded or directly opened in a programm installed on that system. For example, a PDF file will be opened in a PDF Viewer if some pdf viewer application is available.

I wrote a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LqZ2NY3FOyK6Xjs6Wz1w?p=preview) which handles `ng-href` in a AngularJS controller `$scope`. I hope this is what you need.

**Your controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fileHref = 'http://www.analysis.im/uploads/seminar/pdf-sample.pdf';
});
```

**Your view:**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <a ng-href="fileHref" download="yourFilename">Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok thank you, supppose if we want to download file inside  ng-click function.how can we achieve this and one more thing here i am seeing <a href="http://www.analysis.im/uploads/seminar/pdf-sample.pdf"> directly given href url .without giving directly I need to give inside ng-click function,can u tell please.

Comment: Make the download via angularJS is not a good way. But if you want to set the download URL via angularJS -> take a look at my example.

Comment: sorry dude i am not able to vote here,minimum i must need 15 reputations for vote up any way i appreciate you.i will try to get and vote this in few a days,thank you.

Comment: Don't understand why you put `ng-href="{{ fileHref() }} "` instead of `ng-href=" fileHref() "` as `ng-href` is angular directive. But, it is working fine for interpolation not for second one.

Comment: I can't find link for download url via angularjs. Please provide it.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer and code to give more details about client side download handling.

Comment: I don't want to use download attribute of HTML. Can I do that in angularjs/javascript way.

Comment: Its the AngularJS/JavaScript/HTML way. You cant force a real download because its allways handled by the client and the application installed on its OS. I explained that in my answer. You can only ensure that the client will trigger a real download without open a installed programm by using `download` attribute. For example click an mp3 link in your browser, it will play directly (I promise). By adding a `download` attribute to that `a` it will be downloaded instead of play.

Comment: But, I want some file to be downloaded when ever the app is visited.

Comment: So fire a click event on that link like `angular.element('#myselector').triggerHandler('click');` when ever the app is visted.

Comment: @lin: The solution is nice. But, this solution is not working for "Authorization: Bearer" token thing or when the content can not be downloaded in unauthorized way. Can you please give a solution for it?

Comment: @Anijit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592709/using-javascript-to-add-custom-http-header-and-trigger-file-download

Comment: The `download` attribute is not supported in IE11 (latest version on Windows 7) and on iOS Safari: https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Answer (score 18):

I had to achieve the functionality. Also had to make sure that it works for all the major supported browsers.
Here's the solution for the same!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Your View/HTML

```
<a target="_self" class="ui right floated btn btn-warning" href ng-click="downloadInvoice()"> Download </a>
```

Your Controller

```
$scope.downloadInvoice = function () {
    $http.post(url,requestData, {responseType:'arraybuffer',headers:header
        })
            .success(function (response) {
                var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});

                var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
                var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
                var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;


                if (isChrome){
                    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                    var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
                    downloadLink.attr('href',url.createObjectURL(file));
                    downloadLink.attr('target','_self');
                    downloadLink.attr('download', 'invoice.pdf');
                    downloadLink[0].click();
                }
                else if(isEdge || isIE){
                    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file,'invoice.pdf');

                }
                else {
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    window.open(fileURL);
                }

            })
};
```

Comment: Really helpful;) I had to change only one thing:  var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'}); to var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});