# download a file using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to download a file using angular js...
I got one link
[It has code for downloading a file using Plunker][1[1]: [Download a file with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872607/download-a-file-with-)
   angularjs/28873580#comment46050222_28873580

when i am trying to download it it says server not found...so i provided another link to download it, then it says download failed..no file there but file is there..

what i am doing wrong!!!!! controller

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.fileHref = 'http://en.unesco.org/inclusivepolicylab/sites/default/files/dummy-pdf_2.pdf';
 });
```

front view

```
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
 <script>
 document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
 </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" 
 src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14">
 </script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 </head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<a ng-href="fileHref" download="yourFilename">Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the file you provided in the link is not exits in the path`http://www.analysis.im/uploads/seminar/pdf-sample.pdf`

Comment: I don't see you making a GET request anywhere in the code you showed us.

Comment: @azad yeah, even if i check with different link it is failing."http://en.unesco.org/inclusivepolicylab/sites/default/files/dummy-pdf_2.pdf "..

Comment: that was the code which i found provided by @lin . so we need to add a get request?@Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

this simplest angular page may help you,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="test" ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <a ng-href="{{fileHref}}" >My PDF</a>

        <script>

            angular.module('test',[]).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.fileHref = 'https://en.unesco.org/inclusivepolicylab/sites/default/files/dummy-pdf_2.pdf';
            });


        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your code...it is showing the pdf but not downloading into my disk..@azad

Comment: you have to manually download it to your PC otherwise GET file as buffer to your angular app and invoke some js download codes if you can access that pdf file without AJAX cross origin access violation