# How can I download an excel file through javascript, while passing an "Authorization" header?

Tags: javascript, ajax, excel, security, http-headers

I need to download an excel file through javascript, and I need to pass along a header with a security token. It seems that this is not possible through typical ajax requests, or through form.submit. Does anyone know of a way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using-javascript-to-add-custom-http-header-and-trigger-file-download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592709/using-javascript-to-add-custom-http-header-and-trigger-file-download?rq=1)