# Print PDF to page with PHP & jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, pdf

So I need a little help with a php script I am writing that loads a PDF in a new tab through a PHP script. I am doing it this way to make sure that the PDF can only be accessed if the user is logged in and has a link to it, otherwise the .htaccess in the parent directory to the PDF blocks access.
I am able to read from the PDF using the code below:

```
$file = '../path-to-file.pdf';
$filename = 'filename.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);
```

The result of this is then passed into an AJAX function shown below which generates a new tab and throws the response onto it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../includes/function.projects.php?view-media=' + item,
        success: function(data) {
            $(window.open().document.body).html(data);
        }
    })
```

This all works smoothly, it's only when the new tab opens, because I am writing the response straight to the documents HTML, I am getting a screen full of text like this:

```
%PDF-1.5 %���� 2 0 obj << /Linearized 1 /L 17007 /H [ 687 126 ] /O 6 /E 16732 /N 1 /T 16731 >>
```

So my question is quite simply this; Has anyone tried managed to do this before? If so, are there any libraries I should be using/headers I'm missing etc
I have already seen this question here but I cannot get the answers people are listing to work so I am out of ideas.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is only a guess, though I have done similar things to secure images. I don't think you can simply pass the data like that through `window.open.document.body` because you're not sending any headers with it. Why not just pop open a window with your `function.projects.php?view-media=' + item` as the url and do a security check at the top of it?

Comment: hm... though look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516463/request-a-file-with-a-custom-header

Comment: Thats a good idea! I already have a function written to check the session so that would be nice and easy to implement. Another way I have just started to look into was to load a pre-built page that passes the url of the PDF through a GET variable and then a JS library takes over to grab it and load the PDF onto the page...I like your idea better though :)

Comment: Good luck! Check out that other link though - perhaps all you need is to convert it to binary and prepend your string with `data:application/pdf;base64,` and your current plan will work.

Comment: If no one answers your question in full, please do come back and put your solution as an answer. I'd like to see what you figure out.

Comment: Yup will do mate, I'll keep tinkering and then as soon as I have something that works smoothly I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right so I have a solution. If someone can come up with a better way of doing this, please let me know but for now this works perfectly! I found a JS library called [PDFObject](https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject) which can be used to make a cross-browser solution for easily embedding PDFs into a html document. With this, I can pass in a PDF link on the server along with a target div for it to embed into (which in my case I have setup inside of a modal so we stay on the same page).

Because we are staying on the same page, I can block access to the entire page using a function I had written previously in the project which redirects the user to the index if they don't have the right access level. Something along the lines of this would work:

```
function checkSession() {
    if(empty($_SESSION)) {
        header("Location: /?cheeky_monkey");
    }
}
```

If the user tried to access the PDF directly, then this code in the htaccess blocks them. It only allows access if being targeted through the application:

```
SetEnvIf Referer "localhost" is_local_referer
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
    Require env is_local_referer
</FilesMatch>
```

With that out the way, all that needs to happen is to throw a URL at the script tag to load when a PDF is clicked on, accomplished through this sequence of code:

> 1. First we need to grab the URL for the PDF (you might be able to skip this step)

To begin with, this javascript is called whenever someone clicks to view a PDF (this call is simply nested as an onclick attribute):

```
function viewMedia(projectID, type, item) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../includes/function.projects.php?cid=' + projectID + '&type=' + type + '&view-media=' + item,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.pdf-script').html('<script>PDFObject.embed("' + data + '", "#the-pdf");</script>');
            $('#viewMediaModal').modal('toggle');
        }
    })
}
```

This is the code that is ran on the php page.

```
public function viewMedia($item) {
    $mediaItems = unserialize($this->media);
    $file = '/path/to/pdf/' . $mediaItems[$item]['file'];
    echo $file;
}
```

An example of the returned data from this function:

```
/path/to/pdf/example-pdf.pdf
```

> 2. Using this to load the PDF

Once we have the correct URL for the PDF and the AJAX returns as successful, the data received back can be used to re-generate the javascript, this time with the new PDF link:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('.pdf-script').html('<script>PDFObject.embed("' + data + '", "#the-pdf");</script>');
    $('#viewMediaModal').modal('toggle');
}
```

This is what the structure of that modal body looks like:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="the-pdf"></div>
    <div class="pdf-script" style="display: none;">
        <script>PDFObject.embed('', '#the-pdf');</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

> 3. The result

The result of the above code sequence toggles a modal that look like the below:
[image]

And if the user tries to access the file directly:
[image]

Comment: Wow - that's really great. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: No worries! :))