# Convert non unicode string to base64 in JavaScript?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, base64

I'm writing a downloader chrome extension. I'm trying to fetch the file with ajax and encode it with `atob(str)` but it only allows plain strings so can't get `data:blah,base64` working.

Comment: sorry,Kevin.I don't really want a library.But still thanks for English improvement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8022521/189093

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make an AJAX call to a binary file and get `data:xxx/xxx;base64,xxx=` in return? This is not going to happen unless the file is returned by the server using Data URI scheme. You need to use `xhr.responseBlob()`.

Similar question was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845215/making-a-chrome-extension-download-a-file), and the answer there should help you. You can also check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165266/downloading-mp3-files-using-html5-blobs-in-a-chrome-extension).

Comment: So, does the xhr.responseBlob() returns a data: URL?