# Downloading files using html5 blobs in a chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, blob

Im trying to achieve the same goal as OP there:
[Downloading mp3 files using html5 blobs in a chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165266/downloading-mp3-files-using-html5-blobs-in-a-chrome-extension/11518906#11518906)
but not the him's code, not the solution offered in discussion does not work for my google-chrome 19.0.1084.46.
Im working in chrome-console on the local (file://) page, and errors for this code:

```
finalUrl = "http://cs1076.userapi.com/u3040678/audio/d7ff6874cfa4.mp3";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", finalURL, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'octet-stream');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) 
    {   
        var bb = new (window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder)();
        bb.append(xhr.responseText);
        var blob = bb.getBlob("application/octet-stream");

        var saveas = document.createElement("iframe");
        saveas.style.display = "none";

        saveas.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob); 

        document.body.appendChild(saveas);

        delete xhr;
        delete blob;
        delete bb;
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

looks like

> OPTIONS http://cs1076.userapi.com/u3040678/audio/d7ff6874cfa4.mp3 405 (Not Allowed) cs1076.userapi.com/u3040678/audio/d7ff6874cfa4.mp3:1
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cs1076.userapi.com/u3040678/audio/d7ff6874cfa4.mp3. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

And the second subquestion:
in according to [How can i generate a file and offer it for download in plain javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175421/how-can-i-generate-a-file-and-offer-it-for-download-in-plain-javascript/11518859#11518859) - is the creation of iframe the best way to offer file to download?

Comment: What happens if you dont run from a file URL or install the extension so it runs from a chrome:// url?

Comment: I didnt yet check this, why you think that result may be different? 
Thank you for comment.

Comment: Chrome has some security policy for file:// urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrew stated your first problem is probably that your doing it from file://.  Try doing it from an extension.
After that you'll probably like to know that from Chrome 19 you can ask for the response from an xhr to be a blob.
Then for saving the file your better off using something like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to save the file.  The iframe way works but you end up with an awful file name.
Here's an example to get you going....

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Download a file and click to save.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Download a file and click to save.",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://raw.github.com/; object-src 'self'",
  "manifest_version" : 2
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js -->
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
    <!-- https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser/tree/no-jquery -->
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser/no-jquery/purl.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="message">Getting File.....</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/so.mp3', true);
xhr.filename = purl('http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/so.mp3').attr('file');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var message = document.querySelector('#message');
    message.parentNode.removeChild(message);

    var link = document.createElement('A');
    link.innerText = 'Download File';
    link.href = '#';
    link.addEventListener('click', saveFile, false);
    document.body.appendChild(link);

};

xhr.onerror = function() {
    var message = document.querySelector('#message');
    message.innerText = 'Error getting file';
    this.filename = '';
}

xhr.send();

saveFile = function() {
    saveAs(xhr.response, xhr.filename); // saveAs function is from FileSaver.js
}
```

Comment: wow man you are awesome!:) thanks a lot!:) wish you will be happy in all your life:)))

Comment: saveAs is most likely referring to https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: @dgm Yeah its from FileSaver.  I edited the post to link to it, sorry for the confusion.