# Chrome Extension write to file system

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to be able to take a screenshot of a page and give the user the option to save it to their desktop (with a standard OS file save prompt). Is this possible from the Chrome Extension environment? I'm not worried about the image side, more the saving to the user file system.

I've looked at the following pages (among others):

[Making a Chrome Extension download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845215/making-a-chrome-extension-download-a-file)

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this HTML5Rocks update: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Here's a demo of this in action: http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/