# How to create a dynamic file + link for download in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, dynamic, download, creation

Typically, HTML pages can have link to documents (PDF, etc...) which can be downloaded from the server.

Assuming a Javascript enabled webpage, is it possible to dynamically create a text document (for example) from within the user browser and add a link to download this document without a round trip to the server (or a minimal one)?

In other word, the user would click on a button, the javascript would generate randoms numbers (for example), and put them in a structure. Then, the javascript (JQuery for example) would add a link to the page to download the result as a text file from the structure.

This objective is to keep all (or at least most) of the workload on the user side.

Is this feasible, if yes how?

Comment: now **2015** we can use **[Blob (MDN link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)** to build URL to download any data created dynamically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By appending a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs) to the page, you can embed a document within the page that can be downloaded. The data portion of the string can be dynamically concatenated using Javascript. You can choose to format it as a URL encoded string or as base64 encoded. When it is base64 encoded, the browser will download the contents as a file. You will have to add a [script](https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64) or jQuery plugin to do the encoding. Here is an example with static data:

```
jQuery('body').prepend(jQuery('<a/>').attr('href','data:text/octet-stream;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh').text('Click to download'))
```

Comment: This won't work in IE and Edge: http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri

Comment: That is incorrect. It will work in IE and Edge for download links. It will not work in IE/Edge for page assets like HTML and CSS files. You could download CSS though, just not use it in a `<link>` tag.

Answer (score 45):

Here's a solution I've created, that allows you to create and download a file in a **single click**:

```
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick='download_file("my_file.txt", dynamic_text())'>Download</button>
    <script>
    function dynamic_text() {
        return "create your dynamic text here";
    }

    function download_file(name, contents, mime_type) {
        mime_type = mime_type || "text/plain";

        var blob = new Blob([contents], {type: mime_type});

        var dlink = document.createElement('a');
        dlink.download = name;
        dlink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        dlink.onclick = function(e) {
            // revokeObjectURL needs a delay to work properly
            var that = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(that.href);
            }, 1500);
        };

        dlink.click();
        dlink.remove();
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I created this by adapting the code from [this HTML5 demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html) and messing around with things until it worked, so I'm sure there are problems with it (please comment or edit if you have improvements!) but it's a **working, single-click solution.**

(at least, it works for me on the latest version of Chrome in Windows 7)

Comment: Awesome... will award the bounty in 23 hours and 55 mins...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It shows the 'hard' work of creating the data URI. Not just saying you need to use them.

Comment: For Firefox, you need document.body.appendChild(dlink) after calling createElement() and then presumably document.body.removeChild(dlink) after dlink.remove().

Comment: Tested Firefox : document.body.appendChild(dlink) needed but no need to removeChild, the remove() is enough.
Thank you ahuff & alexander !

Comment: just checked on Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit), WORKS!

Comment: You can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to avoid `var that = this;`.

Comment: I believe that browsers will not honor the download attribute if the file is a PDF, and instead do whatever the browser settings say they will do for PDFs, this is true at least for chrome

Answer (score 10):

A PDF file? No. A `txt` file. Yes. With the recent HTML5 `blob` URIs. A very basic form of your code would look something like this:

```
window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;
window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
var file = new window.BlobBuilder(),
    number = Math.random().toString(); //In the append method next, it has to be a string
file.append(number); //Your random number is put in the file

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file.getBlob('text/plain'));
a.download = 'filename.txt';
a.textContent = 'Download file!';
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

You can use the other methods mentioned in the other answers as a fallback, perhaps, since BlobBuilder probably [isn't supported](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=BlobBuilder) very well.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4TJPq/)

**Note:** `BlobBuilder` seems to be deprecated. [Refer to this answer to see how to use `Blob` instead of `BlobBuilder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030906/how-to-replace-the-deprecated-blobbuilder-with-the-new-blob-constructor/15031019#15031019). Thanks to [@limonte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331425/limonte) for the heads up.