# Can I create xml using jQuery or use server side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Is it possible to create an xml file using jQuery or will I have to use server side functions?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "file". To use the literal definition, no - you cannot create server-side files purely using client-side JavaScript. However, creating an XML string is simple.

Comment: i didnt want to say file .what i mean create an xml string.but after i will be able to use Xquery to query like i would do in  a database

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is a javascript library which runs on the client side/browser. To write to the server you need to use a server side tool. ex. ASP, Python, Php.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery ajax to send some data to a server page (ASP.NET/ PHP) and create the XML there.

The below sample makes a call to an ASP.NET MVC action method where i am creating an XML document using the data passed and saving it the disk.I am using the `LINQtoXML` API for this example

```
 $.post("Home/CreateXML", { name : "Angel", age : "22" } function(data){
       alert("Response from server is : "+data);
 });
```

And in your Server side,

```
public ActionResult CreateXML(string name,string age)
{
  XElement elm=new XElement("SomeXML",
                     new XElement("Name",name),
                     new XElement("Age",age));

 elm.Save("C:\\somexml.xml") 
 return Content("XML Created and saved in disk!");   
}
```

Executing this will create an XML in this form

```
 <SomeXML>
    <Name>Angel</Name>
    <Age>Angel</Age>
 </SomeXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create xml content for your xml file and then set it in href as base64.

Check this thread:
[How to create a dynamic file + link for download in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310657/how-to-create-a-dynamic-file-link-for-download-in-javascript)