# Save Event in Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, icalendar

Hi this question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334703/save-event-as-icalendar-using-javascript) but this one saves the event as .ics format. I'm thinking of something like when a link is click it will open the google and save it automatically just like the screen below [image]. So its something like the image below after I click a link it will redirect me to the google calendar page

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text={{ text }}&dates={{ start }}/{{ end }}&details={{ details }}&location={{ location }}&sf=true&output=xml';

$event = [
    'text' => 'Your Event Name',
    'start' => date('Ymd\THis\Z', strtotime('today')),
    'end' => date('Ymd\THis\Z', strtotime('tomorrow')),
    'details' => 'Click here for more details: http://example.com',
    'location' => 'Waldorf Astoria, 301 Park Ave , New York, NY 10022'
];

foreach ($event as $key => $value) {
    $url = str_replace("{{ $key }}", urlencode($value), $url);
}

echo $url;
```

When you navigate to the generated URL, the page should look like on the screenshot.