# How can I create a Javascript bookmarklet to create an Outlook calendar event from the current page?

Tags: javascript, outlook, bookmarklet

I'd like to create a bookmarklet (bookmark that runs some JavaScript) that takes the URL of the current web page, along with some basic content, and opens a new window (or tab) and stars an Outlook calendar event.

I found this old post about doing this with Google Calendars:
https://medium.com/@wifeofvillon/bookmarklet-to-create-a-google-calendar-event-from-title-and-hours-ee03656719d8

Also found this Chrome addin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/add-to-calendar/jnbpajadakhkpcncmbfhkgaaoioofkfd

I'd like to do something similar so when I'm sitting on a webpage, I can click the bookmark and create a calendar event to come back to this page for later review. The following properties should already be set:

`Title: {Current web page title}`

`Location: {Current web page URL}`

`Description: <h1>{Current Web Page Title}</h1><div><a href="{Current Web Page Url}">{Current Web Page Title}</a></div><div>{Current Web Page Selected Text}</div>`

From here, I can customize the event with info about when I'm going to come work on this, read this, etc.

I see this as useful to come back and review important content when I have more time, schedule time to work on tasks tied to a URL, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can generate an ICS file which is a standard format for calendar events. The downloaded file will hopefully be opened by your calendar application to allow import of that event.

Selected text is taken using `window.getSelection()`,
Creating an ICS file adapted from [here](https://codepen.io/vlemoine/pen/MLwygX),
Downloading that file adapted from [How to create a dynamic file + link for download in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310657/how-to-create-a-dynamic-file-link-for-download-in-javascript).

This is the code for the snippet:

```js
function convertDate(date) {
  var event = new Date().toISOString();
  event = event.split("T")[0];
  event = event.split("-");
  event = event.join("");
  return event;
}


function download_file(name, contents, mime_type) {
  mime_type = mime_type || "text/plain";

  var blob = new Blob([contents], {
    type: mime_type
  });

  var dlink = document.createElement('a');
  dlink.download = name;
  dlink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  dlink.onclick = function(e) {
    var href = this.href;
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
    }, 1500);
  };

  dlink.click();
  dlink.remove();
}

var selectedText = window.getSelection() || "";
var ics = `BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//Test Cal//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:test-1
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:${convertDate()}
SUMMARY:${document.title}
DESCRIPTION:${selectedText}
LOCATION:${window.location}
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR  
`;

download_file('webpage-event.ics', ics);
```

And courtesy of [Mr. coles website](https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) this is the final minified result for the bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bfunction%20convertDate(date)%20%7Bvar%20event%20%3D%20new%20Date().toISOString()%3Bevent%20%3D%20event.split(%22T%22)%5B0%5D%3Bevent%20%3D%20event.split(%22-%22)%3Bevent%20%3D%20event.join(%22%22)%3Breturn%20event%3B%7Dfunction%20download_file(name%2C%20contents%2C%20mime_type)%20%7Bmime_type%20%3D%20mime_type%20%7C%7C%20%22text%2Fplain%22%3Bvar%20blob%20%3D%20new%20Blob(%5Bcontents%5D%2C%20%7Btype%3A%20mime_type%7D)%3Bvar%20dlink%20%3D%20document.createElement('a')%3Bdlink.download%20%3D%20name%3Bdlink.href%20%3D%20window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)%3Bdlink.onclick%20%3D%20function(e)%20%7Bvar%20href%20%3D%20this.href%3BsetTimeout(function()%20%7Bwindow.URL.revokeObjectURL(href)%3B%7D%2C%201500)%3B%7D%3Bdlink.click()%3Bdlink.remove()%3B%7Dvar%20selectedText%20%3D%20window.getSelection()%20%7C%7C%20%22%22%3Bvar%20ics%20%3D%20%60BEGIN%3AVCALENDAR%5CnCALSCALE%3AGREGORIAN%5CnMETHOD%3APUBLISH%5CnPRODID%3A-%2F%2FTest%20Cal%2F%2FEN%5CnVERSION%3A2.0%5CnBEGIN%3AVEVENT%5CnUID%3Atest-1%5CnDTSTART%3BVALUE%3DDATE%3A%24%7BconvertDate()%7D%5CnSUMMARY%3A%24%7Bdocument.title%7D%5CnDESCRIPTION%3A%24%7BselectedText%7D%5CnLOCATION%3A%24%7Bwindow.location%7D%5CnEND%3AVEVENT%5CnEND%3AVCALENDAR%5Cn%60%3Bdownload_file('webpage-event.ics'%2C%20ics)%7D)()
```