jquery how to download inline data as a file
Say I have a database driven website with lots of events, each event is loaded and displayed on a listing page.
I want to present the data of each event as a download (lets say an eventname.txt file) that can be downloaded from clicking a link. The file data comes from either the database or from inline elements on the page, it is not a resource file media.
Example data, say:
Home: Sausages
Date: July 2024
Purpose: Stack!
Author: The Capt'n. 

This data needs to be generated by Javascript on page load and put into a form that on clicking a button/link an event.txt file that can be offered for download by the client, but the file doesn't exist on the server.
How can I do this with JQuery?
I imagine something like This answer to a vaguely related question.
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  var textdata = "Home: Sausages\nDate: July 2024\nPurpose: Stack!\nAuthor: The Capt'n.";
  link.download = thefilename;
  // Construct the uri
  var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;' + textdata
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  // Cleanup the DOM
  document.body.removeChild(link);

I have looked for other questions asking this but I think I don't know the correct words as I can't see anything that really helps guide me here.

What's the problem? Do you need help with converting JSON data into string?

Instead of using a data: URL, use a URL that points to the server script that looks up the data in the database and returns it. link.download will make it download to a file.

Do you want to do this in Client or in Server?

Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310657/how-to-create-a-dynamic-file-link-for-download-in-javascript

To clarify: All the data is already on the page; @Barmar. I'm looking for something to take some of the text strings that are already on the page and to wrap them in a file for the purposes of downloading for the end user. This "file" that they save doesn't need to exist on the server, but is generated from the text strings already on the page.

@Twisty being Jquery I am looking at doing this client side with data the client already has on the page.

In that case, what's wrong with the code you posted? I thought when you wrote "Say I have a database driven website" that the data was in a database, too large to put it all on the page.

@Barmar ok if the code (which I got from the linked question) can work for this concept, that's great. It's more that I'd done some initial searching and hadn't been able to find anything practical since 2014 that approached this concept. But there are a few useful links posted in the Q so will explore these tomorrow :)

Consider something like:


$(function() {
  function readTableToObject(table) {
    var result = {};
    $("tbody > tr", table).each(function(i, row) {
      result[$("td", row).eq(0).text().trim()] = $("td", row).eq(1).text().trim()
    });
    return result;
  }

  function objectToText(obj, eol, enc) {
    if (obj == undefined) {
      return false;
    }
    if (eol == undefined) {
      eol = "\r\n";
    }
    if (enc == undefined) {
      enc = true;
    }
    var txt = "";
    $.each(obj, function(k, v) {
      txt += k + ": " + v + eol;
    });
    if (enc) {
      return encodeURI(txt);
    }
    return txt;
  }

  function downloadData(table) {
    console.log("Reading Data from Table: " + $(table).attr("id"));
    var myData = readTableToObject(table);
    var textData = objectToText(myData);
    var link = $("<a>", {
      href: 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;' + textData,
      class: "download-link",
      download: $(table).attr("id") + ".txt"
    }).appendTo("body");
    link.trigger("click").remove();
  }

  $("button[id^='btn-']").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id") + " Clicked");
    var i = $(this).attr("id").slice(-2);
    downloadData($("#data-" + i));
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".download-link", function() {
    console.log("Download Link Clicked.", $(this).attr("href"));
  });

});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table id="data-01">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Home</td>
        <td>Sausages</td>
      </tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>July 2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Purpose</td>
        <td>Stack!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td>The Capt'n.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button id="btn-01">Download Data</button>
</div>



May not work in all browsers.
Ref: How to create a dynamic file + link for download in Javascript?

This looks like the kind of thing I'm trying to reach, yes, thank you. I will explore further in the morning :)
