# Working with files NPAPI/PPAPI/NSPR

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi, nspr, ppapi

I need in Chrome extension these actions:

- Download binary file to temp
- Unzip it (it's clear .zip package)
- Move files from unpacked directory, to directory of my extension
- Delete temp files

I've been looking for similar what Firefox Scriptable XPCOM interfaces offer, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference

Is there any simple way to do this, or I need to create the components myself in C/C++ and one of NPAPI, PPAPI, NSPR ?

Comment: I can't speak to the capabilities of a chrome extensions, but if you do need to use C++ you'll be looking at NPAPI; PPAPI was essentially discontinued (replaced by NaCl, which *might* be able to dow hat you want, but not sure) and NSPR is just a runtime/utility library. XPCOM support is also gone from plugins as of FF 3.6. Check out http://firebreath.org if you do decide you need to use C++; it'll speed things up a lot.

Comment: The [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) might be enough in this case.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche can you please expand your comment to answer, and list out what parts of `Filesystem API` should I use for these actions? Thanks

Comment: @AdamAyres yep, I've seen it, but problem is I'm not very good in pure C/C++ and I need to support multiple platforms (osx,win,lnx)

Comment: @taxilian hmm, strange, I use XPCOM (but maybe JSCOM) on Firefox since Gecko 1.9.1 to 9 without problem, can you post some relevant info? Thanks

Comment: @MarekSebera perhaps you're using a technique with which I'm unfamiliar, then; I do know that with NPAPI plugins you can't use XPCOM anymore, but maybe there is a way to make a C++ extension using it.

Comment: @Marek: If you can [get the data in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845215/making-a-chrome-extension-download-a-file) you can write it & read it back using the methods in the article. Not having walked through this myself i can only assume that that'll work.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I am working on an extension with a similar requirement, I managed to implement unzipping process entirely in javascript using a library, and it works... but man it is SLOW :(

Comment: @Matthew nope, I've left the problem, have you done any progress? I'd be glad for appropriate answer.