# Download in chrome extension not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension and it needs to download a file that has been created using blob I tried this ([Making a Chrome Extension download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845215/making-a-chrome-extension-download-a-file)):

```
var aFilePart = ['<a id="a"><b id="b">Hi :) !</b></a>'];
var blob = new Blob(aFilePart, {type : 'text/html'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

chrome.downloads.download({
  url: url 
});
```

But I get no download going. Help?

Comment: Are you sure you've set the `"download"` permission in your *manifest.json*? Where are you calling this? From bg or content script?

Comment: Yes i did add Download to the manifest and i called it from popup.js

Comment: I think you've got to call it from background scripts

Comment: That's it ! Thanks a lot !