# Download attribute not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Im fixing a chrome extension that i've been running for awhile now and the download feature that had worked for awhile is broken and i've had trouble getting it to work again. In one of my extension "options" pages (the URL starts with `chrome-extension://...`) I used to be able to download a file using an `a` HTML tag and I could control the name of the file being downloaded. Looked something like this-

```
<a href="https://www.another_domain.com/..." download="custom name">Download</a>
```

My extension has full permissions to `"another_domain.com"` and I actually have tested it with just giving the extension full permissions to all domains. My permissions from the manifest file (extracted other permissions that aren't relevant)-

```
 "permissions": ["*://*/*"]
```

A user used to be able to simply click the link and download the file, which would be named according to the download attribute. Now, the file still downloads but is named "download" by the server and isn't of much use to the user. I read [from this source](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-using-the-html5-download-attribute--cms-23880) that cross-domain downloads are allowed in Chrome but I cannot change the name. I'm wondering if this has always been the case or if this is a recent change. If it's a recent change, then any suggestions on work-arounds are appreciated.

Comment: Did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845215/making-a-chrome-extension-download-a-file

Comment: There was also a bug in Chrome 65 for a week or so, see https://crbug.com/798705

Comment: The duplicate question pretty much helped me get to where I needed to go, but the <a> tag not working as expected is stil confusing. Not a problem I need to worry about when working with extensions though!