# Downloading storage data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am currently trying to download some data I have saved in chrome's local storage as a file.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721439/download-json-object-as-a-file-from-browser) was the way I used before, however it seems that the data is too big to be downloaded in this manner.

The data size is abut 1.8MB, but I'm planning to add more data in the future, probably would add up to around 3MB.

[what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQfdq.png)

I have an array with around 1600 items, each item being an array from about 30 to 100+ items each.

I also have another array with around 8000 items, while each item is an array which contains 4 items of its own.

Comment: Use createObjectURL as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305829) or chrome.downloads API as shown in other answers there.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you very much. This worked.