# jquery file save as dialog box

Tags: jquery

How to open file save as dialog box using jquery in firefox ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Context is key..

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish (saving the current page, or a different page you're linking to, or a file)? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting? (please be more specific, none these are self-evident from the current state of your question)

Answer (score 2):

I hope these past answers can help you:

[Is it possible to catch browser's File Open/Save dialog event using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197955/is-it-possible-to-catch-browsers-file-open-save-dialog-event-using-javascript)

[Open the Save Image dialog using jQuery/Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399486/open-the-save-image-dialog-using-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Hi , I want to open file save as dialog box on button click . As we do in file->saveAs.I am developing a web application where i need to do that to save my current web page contents.

Comment: Answers that I posted are the key. It's not possible to do that because there aren't any event associated to open 'Save dialog'