# Ways to open Save as Dialog box on button click in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Is there any way to trigger "Save as" dialog box in asp.net. I know it is not possible in Java Script to control client's machine. Is there any way to trigger the dialog box on Click of a dowload button. The scenario is I generate a XML, which must be downloaded on client's machine. The "Save as " dialog box should pop up on the button click. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How much research did you do on your own? I've googled for less than one 1 min and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027632/jquery-file-save-as-dialog-box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery file save as dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027632/jquery-file-save-as-dialog-box)

Comment: I don't want to download the web page. I need to download the  XML which gets generated in the Web Page Itself in the client's hard drive. Thanks. If that is possible in Javascript, then there occurs security issues.

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
String FileName = "FileName.txt";
String FilePath = "C:/...."; //Replace this
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName 
+ ";");
response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Comment: Thanks , but I've tried this code already. This helps in picking up the file and download it in the default folder of the browser and does not trigger "Save as " dialog box.